# How to draw smooth circle in Libgdx

Tags: libgdx, android, antialiasing

I am trying to draw an circle to Libgdx which is created from Image not ShapeRenderer. But when I try to draw image to SpriteBatch it does not draw smoothly. 
[image: This is the Image that I am using]

[image: This is the Image that drawing]

I checked the image resolution and Image Dimension is 1673x1673 and Sprite Size is 80x80.

```
  //This is my GameState code
  @Override
    public void render(float delta) {
        update(delta);
        SpriteBatch sb = game.batch;
        Color bg = ThemeFactory.getInstance().getTheme().backgroundColor;
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(bg.r, bg.g, bg.b, bg.a);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        sb.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
        sb.begin();
        for(int i =0;i<elements.size();i++){
            if(!(elements.get(i) instanceof Arrow)){
                elements.get(i).render(sb);//HERE IS DRAWING HAPPENING
            }
        }
        sb.end();
        barriers.render(sb);
        renderHud();
    }
```

My circle constructor and rendering code is below.

```
public Circle(Texture texture, Size size, Vector3 position){
        mSprite = new Sprite(texture);
        mSprite.setSize(size.width, size.height);//80x80
        mSprite.setPosition(position.x, position.y);
        mSprite.setOriginCenter();
    }
@Override
public void render(SpriteBatch sb) {
    mSprite.draw(sb);
}
```

I tried **TextureFilters Nearest Nearest and Linear Linear** but nothing has changed. And also increased **samples** for desktop and android applications, nothing has changed too.

Comment: Did you set the `Min` or `Mag` filter?

Comment: What is min or mag filter ?

Comment: When applying the filter you use `texture.setFilter(minFilter, magFilter)`. What did you set the min and mag filters to? I would suggest trying `TextureFilter.MipMapLinearNearest` on `Min` and `TextureFilter.Nearest` on mag and see if it gives a satisfactory result.

Comment: TextureFilter.MipMapLinearNearest gives me a  black rectangle, I have tried Nearest but it did not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Libgdx has to know to build the mip map. Use this constructor with the second parameter set to true

```
Texture(FileHandle file, boolean useMipMaps)
```

It's not really clear what you mean by "smoothly", different TextureFilters will affect the way it draws in different ways. In any case, mipmaps should be "best" for drawing a high-res texture at low res.